# Generic named functions arguments in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

It stretches a bit the scope of C++, but hey, they gave us the 17 standard, so why not? Some snippet were found all over the internet, but the whole implementation is original.

Here is an example main:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "NamedArgs.hpp"

// Declare named type arguments with the NamedArg helper macro
// NamedArg(TypeName, InterfaceName, TypedDefaultValue)
NamedArg(TName, n, std::string{"John"})
NamedArg(TSurn, s, std::string{"Doe"})

// Define a usual function using the TypesNames above
void intro( TName nm, TSurn sm) {
  std::cout << "My name is " << sm << ", "
            << nm << " " << sm << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  // Define a wrapper functor accepting position independent
  // named arguments with the NamedArgsFunc helper macro
  // NamedArgsFunc(Function, InterfaceName)    
  NamedArgsFunc(intro, I)

  // Calling the wrapper function with InterfaceNames in any arrangement
  I();
  I( n="James" );
  I( s="Bond", n="James" );
  I( n="Bond", s="James" );
  return 0;
}
```

...and its output:

```
/****************************
My name is Doe, John Doe
My name is Doe, James Doe
My name is Bond, James Bond
My name is James, Bond James
****************************/
```

Here is `NamedArgs.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

///////////////////
// User's macros //
///////////////////

// Declaration of Named Args
#define NamedArg(Name, ShortName, DefaultTypeValue) \
struct Name: NamedArgs::BaseType<decltype(DefaultTypeValue)> { \
  Name(decltype(DefaultTypeValue) d = DefaultTypeValue): \
    BaseType{std::move(d)} {} \
}; \
static const NamedArgs::Builder<Name> ShortName;

// Instantiate the wrapper for free and lambda functions
#define NamedArgsFunc(FunctionName, WrapperName) \
static const NamedArgs::FuncWrapper<FunctionName> WrapperName;

// Instantiate the wrapper for member functions -- use inside a class
// Example: NamedArgsMemeberFunc( &ClassName::MemberFunc, operator() )
#define NamedArgsMemberFunc(FunctionName, WrapperName) \
template <typename... Args> \
auto WrapperName(Args&& ... args) { \
  return NamedArgs::FuncWrapper<FunctionName>{} \
    (this, std::forward<Args>(args)...); \
}

////////////////////
// Implementation //
////////////////////

#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

namespace NamedArgs {

// check if T1 is the same of one of the T2...    
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr bool check_for_type() {
  return std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>...>;
}

// given a function construct a tuple with its list of arguments
template <typename R, typename... Args>
auto function_args(R (*)(Args...)) {
  return std::tuple<Args...>();
}

// given a member function construct a tuple with its list of arguments
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
auto function_args(R (T::*)(Args...)) {
  return std::tuple<Args...>();
}

// given a const member function construct a tuple with its list of arguments
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
auto function_args(R (T::*)(Args...) const) {
  return std::tuple<Args...>();
}

// given a lambda function construct a tuple with its list of arguments
template <typename Lambda>
auto function_args(const Lambda &) {
  return function_args(&Lambda::operator());
}

// Helper enabling syntax InterfaceName=value directly in the function call
template <typename T>
struct Builder {
  T operator=(typename T::value_type&& value) const { return T{value}; }
  Builder() = default;
  Builder(Builder const&) = delete;
  Builder(Builder&&) = delete;
  Builder& operator=(Builder const&) = delete;
  Builder& operator=(Builder&&) = delete;
};

// Base class for NamedArgs
template <typename T>
struct BaseType {
  using value_type = T;
  value_type value;

  BaseType() = delete;
  BaseType(BaseType const&) = default;
  BaseType(BaseType&&) = default;
  BaseType& operator=(BaseType const&) = default;
  BaseType& operator=(BaseType&&) = default;

  BaseType(value_type v): value{std::move(v)} {}
  BaseType& operator=(value_type v) { value = std::move(v); return *this;}

  operator value_type&() {return value;}
  operator const value_type&() const {return value;}
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BaseType<T>& t) {
  os << t.value;
  return os;
}

template <auto func>
struct FuncWrapper {
  template <typename... Args>
  auto operator()(Args&& ... args) const {
    auto passed_args = std::tie( args... );
    auto needed_args = function_args(func);

    auto copy_if_passed = [&passed_args]( auto & a ) {
      if constexpr ( NamedArgs::check_for_type<decltype(a), Args...>() ) {
        a = std::get<decltype(a)>(passed_args);
      }
    };

    std::apply( [&](auto && ... needed_arg) {
      (( copy_if_passed(needed_arg) ), ...);
    }, needed_args);

    if constexpr( std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(func)> ) {
      auto ClassPTR = std::get<0>(passed_args);
      auto bind = [ClassPTR](auto &&... args) { 
        return (ClassPTR->*func)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); 
      };
      return std::apply(bind, needed_args);
    } else {
      return std::apply(func, needed_args);
    }
  }
};

} //namespace NamedArgs
```